# How can show number + more of remain text from string array fixed to div width by using javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, ellipsis

[image]

I want to show string array separated by commas in div has width(ex: 300px). When text's longer than div width, it will show text has three dots and + (number of remain texts in array) like the picture above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
var main = document.querySelector('main');
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var stringArr = ['Apple', 'Grape fruit', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'KiwiJuice', 'Tangerine'];

function dotdotdot(list){
  var ix, ixLen, listLen;
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = ' + ';
  
  // 1. insert a text into an element
  // 2. compare the scrollWidth and the clientWidth
  //    if scrollWidth is bigger than the other, it means the text has been overflowed
  // 3. find the index of the text which has been overflowed
  // 4. insert <span>+ ?more</span>
  // * when compare two scrollWidths, consider the width of <span> because of the max-width of <main> tag. 
  // * the width of <span> is set by 150 px as an example.
  for(ix = 0, ixLen = list.length; ix < ixLen; ix++){
     if(ix !== ixLen - 1){
       //main.textContent += list[ix] + ', ';
       p.textContent += list[ix] + ', ';
     }else{
       //main.textContent += list[ix];
       p.textContent += list[ix];
     }
     
     if(p.scrollWidth > main.scrollWidth - 150){
       //p.style.overflow = 'hidden';
       //p.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis';
       p.style.width = p.clientWidth + 'px';
       
       span.textContent += list.length - (ix + 1);
       span.textContent += 'more';
       main.append(span);
       return;
     }
  }
}

dotdotdot(stringArr);
```

```css
main {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p></p>
</main>
```

Comment: Good solution, but I will count number remain element from array with max-width of <main>. Ex: <main> has max-width = 400px and ellipsis, expectation of me is Apple, Orange, Banana, Kiwi... + 1more  OR Apple, Orange bac mmm yyyyyy... + 3more 0R 192.168.56.178-Windows server 2012R2 environment...+4 more

Comment: Mm, I don't think I got your point. So, you mean, if the width of `<main>` is 400px, and then the length of values printed in `<main>` shouldn't be overflowed over `<main>`, right? If it would seem so, '... + 4 more' should be printed?

Comment: Yes, if long text in position 1, or 2,... is will show 192.168.56.178-Windows server 2012R2 environment...+4 more, if text is shorter it will show  Apple, Orange bac mmm yyyyyy... + 3more according to max-width.

Comment: Thanks for your support :) But I think I will not use jQuery or library. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're okay, can I make that function you want when I get home?

Comment: @Tam Vo, Sorry for being late, I’ve just got home, I’ll edit my codes with in hours!!

Comment: No problem bro, I'm excited to discuss with you :)

Comment: 1 question, if the text is too long, for example “abcdefghijklmnop”, should it be like “abcde...” too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160208/discussion-between-tam-vo-and-moon).

Answer (score -1):

Try using this on your div:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Yes, text-overflow: ellipsis I can show "abc, xyz ...." but I want to show extra information is "abc, xyz, ....+ 3 more" if my array has 5 elements :)

Comment: Okay. You could just input a span tag like so after the text ellipsis div: `<span class="extra-items-blue>+${extraItems.length}
 more</span>`